# CONCATENATE is not working in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 16.0
Windows 10
Lenovo Z70-80
Intel(R) Core i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40 Ghz, 2401 Mhz, 2 Cores, 4 Logical

I am trying to use an excel GUID subroutine i found. It works perfect when used as a formula in a cell, but will not work when called as a Subroutine module.

```
= CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 4294967295), 8), "-", DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 42949), 4), "-", DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 42949), 4), "-", DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 42949), 4), "-", DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 4294967295), 8), DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 42949), 4))
```

I have teased this apart and discovered the problem is the CONCATENATE function which gets a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

I have both atpvbaen.xls and VBAProject Add-Ons installed. The add-ons show up checked under Tools References and they show up in the VBA Editor file explorer above my project folders.

Some of the add-on functions work such as Dec2Hex and RandBetween.

---

Calling from a SubRoutine

Works --> p = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 999)

Works --> p = Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(1234, 5)

NO Work --> p = Application.WorksheetFunction.CONCATENATE("-", "a")

---

As a Formula in a Cell

Works --> =CONCATENATE("-","a")

Works --> =CONCATENATE(8,"a")

Works --> =CONCATENATE((RANDBETWEEN(1, 999)),"XXX")

---

I have spent hours searching for help and testing and I would greatly appreciate some guidance.
Thanks - Gary

Comment: Why do you need to use that worksheet function in VBA? There are numerous other methods for combining strings together. Ex: `p = Join(Array("-", "a"), vbNullString)`

Comment: `Concatenate()` isn't a method of the `WorksheetFunction` object. No changing of the project references will fix that. Perhaps you can use `&` or `Join` instead.

Comment: It was part of a cell formula as i noted above to generate a GUID. I wrongly assumed what works in a cell will work the same in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

`Concatenate` isn't an Excel Function that can be called from VBA. You can use `Join()` or simple concatenation, `&`, instead. If you really don't like having to wrap the arguments in an array before calling `Join()`, you can roll your own:

```
Function Concatenate(ParamArray Strings()) As String
    Concatenate = Join(Strings, "")
End Function
```

Used like:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Concatenate("A", "B", "C")
End Sub
```

Which just prints `ABC` to the immediate window.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221602(v=office.11).aspx) discusses why `CONCATENATE` isn't callable from VBA:

> Note  Some worksheet functions aren't useful in Visual Basic. For
>   example, the Concatenate function isn't needed because in Visual Basic
>   you can use the & operator to join multiple text values.

Comment: Thanks John - I will go over the documentation link you suggested. I see how i can do a work around.

Answer (score -1):

CONCATENATE might not be a VBA function but CONCAT is:

```
ConcatedCells = WorksheetFunction.Concat(range("A1:C1"))
```